# How to install dia on my debian8 64 cpu?

Tags: debian, cpu, 64bit, 32bit

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
root@hws:/home/debian8# dpkg -i   /home/debian8/Downloads/dia_0.97.2-5_i386.deb
Selecting previously unselected package dia.
(Reading database ... 87794 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dia_0.97.2-5_i386.deb ...
Unpacking dia (0.97.2-5) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dia:
 dia depends on libc6 (>= 2.7).
 dia depends on libcairo2 (>= 1.2.4).
 dia depends on libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1).
 dia depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0).
 dia depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0).
 dia depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.12.0).
 dia depends on libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.18.0).
 dia depends on libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4).
 dia depends on libxml2 (>= 2.7.4).
 dia depends on dia-common (= 0.97.2-5).
 dia depends on dia-libs (= 0.97.2-5).

dpkg: error processing package dia (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dia
root@hws:/home/debian8# apt-get install -y libc6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done
libc6 is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dia:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
            Depends: libcairo2:i386 (>= 1.2.4) but it is not installable
            Depends: libfreetype6:i386 (>= 2.2.1) but it is not installable
            Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.22.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.24.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libgtk2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.12.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libpango1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.18.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libpng12-0:i386 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not installable
            Depends: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.7.4) but it is not installable
            Depends: dia-common:i386 (= 0.97.2-5) but it is not installable
            Depends: dia-libs:i386 (= 0.97.2-5) but it is not installable
            Recommends: gsfonts-x11:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@hws:/home/debian8# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  dia:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 592 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 87802 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing dia (0.97.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58) ...
root@hws:/home/debian8# apt-get install -y libc6:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done
Package libc6:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

It is no use to `dpkg --add-architecture i386` to install dia 32 deb package.
How to install it on my debian8 64 bit cpu?

Hi cas ,it is true that no amd:64 deb package in the download link at
[url]http://sourceforge.net/projects/dia-installer/files/latest/download?source=top3_dlp_t5[/url]

[image]

I install it with `apt-get install dia` on my 64 bit debian,think to oaima.

Comment: why do you even want to install a 32-bit version of dia when there is a 64-bit package available?

Comment: no 64 deb package of  dia to download .

Comment: then why do i have dia:amd64 installed on my debian system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the repositories and don't try to install packages with the wrong architecture and dependencies.

```
aptitude purge dia
apt-get update
apt-get install dia
```